# Upload image with php on the web from android tablet devices

Tags: php, android, image-upload

I've build a web project that could upload and resize image with the following script and i did minor change on it:
http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop/

It works fine on desktop computers and samsung galaxy s gingerbread. But when i tried on android tablets such as samsung galaxy tab the upload feature failed. Everything works fine until the upload button is clicked. It get stucked at upload.php ( a file that i created separate from a single php file as demonstrated by webmotionuk ), it shows blank after the upload process a while and suppose it direct to secondpage.php after the upload finished.

I've tried to direct access to secondpage.php once the upload progress bar stopped to try to displayed the image but it doesn't work. i've checked the server the image selected wasn't being upload as well.

All the features and functions mention above works fine on desktop computers except android tablets.

I've done a lot research on this on the web but couldn't find any solution for web based. Many discussions are related to android app development

Comment: does web-Gmail work in these browsers, i.e. attaching files via upload?

Comment: Hi dldnh, sorry i don't really get what you mean. I tried to view the files that uploaded from a desktop computer it works accordingly. Never try to send as an attachment with an email, but i did try to send the image as a link with email and it does display on my inbox. Would you mind if i ask does this has anything to do with it? Was this purpose try to verify does the image display properly or as a web format? Thank you

Comment: what I meant was that Gmail's web app lets you upload files to use as attachments when you send an email. I wonder if that function works in the browsers you're having trouble with or whether the problem affects their app as well.

Comment: Hi dldnh, thanks for your reply. i've tested the gmail's web app that works fine. But still i couldn't upload image from android tablets to the server in web form with php. Cheers

Comment: well, don't give up -- now you know there must be something that will make it work.

Comment: Thanks dldnh, i'm really appreciate for your attention. I really have no idea why is this happening because everything works fine on a desktop computer. And i couldn't find any relevant topics of uploading  files via android devices browser. If you wouldn't mind and if you got any clue or tips that might help i will be very appreciate. Thanks again

Comment: my first suggestion would be to find as many applications as you can that allow uploading of files, and see if they also work in the tablet browsers that are troublesome, which will help you know how widespread this issue is in general. another suggestion is to write a test site that does nothing at all but allow you to upload a file. if there is no other application logic involved, you may discover something you weren't aware of before.